# How do I spawn only a certain number of threads or tasks and then wait and as each thread or task completes, spawn a new thread or task in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I am creating a data cleansing application that loops through the tables in a database and cleanses NPI data from the different columns. I have created a class for each of the tables that has a method that performs the cleansing operation. What I want to do is loop over the table classes and using reflection call each class and its cleansing method. I would like to do 10 tables at a time and as one table completes, spawn a new thread/task on the next table in the list.

I have a treeview where the user can select one or more tables from the database to cleanse. I have been able to loop over the selected tables and invoke the cleanse method for each table on its own thread, but I end up with over 100 threads (if all tables are selected) executing at the same time. Not an ideal situation.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I am using C# and .NET 4.6, so Task code would be preferred.

Comment: Are you possibly looking for a [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: to piggyback off of @qJake specifically the SetMaxThreads method is of importance to you in this situation

Comment: It's not really necessary to create a separate thread pool for this, and you probably don't want to affect the default thread pool as other parts of the application might be unintentionally affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple approach is to use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992041(v=vs.110).aspx) with the [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx) option set to the maximum threads you would like.

A more advanced and rather elegant framework for this kind of problem is the [Dataflow Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) (TPL). Use an ActionBlock to perform the work and set it's degree of parallelism as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You better using `Task`, as it implements inside [Work sharing](http://www.drdobbs.com/work-stealing-queues-in-net-4-and-in-pre/228800432): which basically means that `Task=Work`, which maps on hardware thread of your OS, via special [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx).

- Threads may not be available always
- There may be more work to do than threads, so if you have a queue to process, the same thread will be used to work over a new data (spawning a thread has its own costs)
- Possible successful False-Sharing management (on CPU cache lines). You may be concerned less, but still worth knowing what it is.
- ..More.

A lot of that *possibly* thought, scheduled and processed by thread scheduler to get optimal generic performance without much hustle. To be clear, you will not get the best possible multi-threaded performance, but you, most likely, do not need that either.

What you are asking about is Data Parallelism.

The simple example of how to use it you can find in: [How to: Write a Simple Parallel.For Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Task Parallel Library, it has a type Task and Task that I think will suite you just fine.

You could create 10 Tasks, put them in a collection and do a Tasks.WhenAny(myTasks).Result. At that point you can figure out how many tasks are done and put more into the collection (IsCompleted property).

Instead of .WhenAny you could probably make it less complicated and use WhenAll(myTasks), and just do this all in batches of x. The parallel foreach answer is also an excellent option, there's a whole world in the TPL for you to explore.

Very basic example, not sure your full context here:

```
var myTasks = new List<Task>();
myTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => someLongProcess))
myTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => someLongProcess))

Task.WhenAny(myTasks).Result
//Check to see how many tasks are done, and then add more to your collection and repeat until you're done
```